# bug with angular2-meteor app :failed connection to mysql via meteor

Tags: mysql, meteor, typescript, angular

i'm trying to connect to mysql  database with meteor using nodets:mysql and i'm facing this error :

```
Unhandled rejection Error: No infromation can be fetched by your database, please check your permissions
```

this is my part of code :

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    //Start of changes

    var connectionSettings = {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'test'
    };

    var db = Mysql.connect(connectionSettings);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i need to add the port of mysql 
Meteor.startup(function() {

```
//Start of changes

var connectionSettings = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port : (mysqlport),
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
};

var db = Mysql.connect(connectionSettings);
```

})